# How can make a label not visible as soon as a user types in an input using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a html as follows

```
<input  ng-required="true" ng-model="Email" type="text" value="">

 and i have a div as follows:

<div  id="invalid" style="display: none">
    <strong><i class="mycustomclass" ></i>Invalid</strong>
</div>
```

How can i make it that as soon as the user types in the input then the div is no longer visible or hidden using Angularjs. I know i need to use ng-show or hide but i cant seem to figure out how to put it together with the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using components it will look like this:

```
<div  id="invalid" data-ng-hide="$ctrl.Email">
    <strong><i class="mycustomclass" ></i>Invalid</strong>
</div>
```

If you are using old controller style:

```
<div  id="invalid" data-ng-hide="Email">
    <strong><i class="mycustomclass" ></i>Invalid</strong>
</div>
```